# Level of data available on FactFinder

Tags: data, census

I am trying to find data at the block level or even block group level for the SF1 files and ACS 2010 or 2009.  Just recently, two months ago, I was able to get this data but for some reason I am now only able to get it at the census tract level??? I have followed all the ways in which I am suppose to extract this data.  Did this change?

Comment: ACS smallest level available is block group, and that is only available for the 5 year estimates (same goes for Census Tracts). Also I don't even think those are available on AFF.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen as well. You can download by Block Group then it will not be available in the Download Center any more.  I believe you can grab the data you are looking for from the census American Community Survey (ACS) FTP site available through the [Summary File Data](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/data/summary-file.html) page of their website, also as pointed out above important FYI - block GROUPS are the smallest level of geography census summarizes ACS data not Blocks - highest precision but least accuracy.